# update publishAt date of a youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to set the publishAt date of a youtube video to 5 minutes from now:

Request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=_VIDEOID_&key=_KEY_

Authorization:  Bearer xxxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

Response

```
200 OK

{
 - snip-
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/ctlUM3pGyXYfW6_IYy2nlhviZZ4\"",
   "id": "_VIDEOID_",
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "private",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

So fine, I get the video info, then I try to set the video's publishAt value

Request

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&key=_KEY_

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "status": {
   "embeddable": true,
   "license": "youtube",
   "privacyStatus": "private",
   "publicStatsViewable": true,
   "publishAt": "2015-01-21T11:20:27.751+00:00"
 },
 "id": "_VIDEOID_"
}
```

Response

```
400 Bad Request

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Any clues?

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The documentation says that i should be able to set the publishAt value. I can't work this one out!

I've tested this using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update and the C# API with the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting the publishAt too close to the current time (5 minutes.) 60 minutes worked.

In my opinion this should be better documented and the UPDATE call should return an error similar to the INSERT (badRequest (400) invalidPublishAt)

Answer (score 1):

To change a field in upload method, you have to put all other fields you get, otherwise the update method will think you are trying to empty them.

In your case, you should include "license" and "publicStatsViewable" in your PUT request just as you get them from your "GET" request.

Comment: Let me test this... when I use the C# API, i modify the return of a .list call (so all the fields should be filled by default - I just modify the publishAt) so I'm not sure this is correct yet

Comment: Whilst you were correct (this was the problem with the google api exporer example), my problem with the C# SDK was that I was trying to set the publishAt time too soon (apparently "in 5 minutes" is not acceptable, but "in 60 minutes" is fine.)