# Update publishAt error invalidVideoMetadata - YOUTUBE v3 API PHP

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use youtube API to update video on youtube.
The problem is that i got this error from youtube when i want to update the video publishAt status.

```html
[2017-11-29 12:19:39] local.ERROR: Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata",
    "message": "The request metadata is invalid.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "body"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request metadata is invalid."
 }
}
```

But the strange thing is that i get the error only if i set the publishAt value (ive updated the privacyStatus to 'private'). If the publishAt is null the update process is successful.

```html
$params     = array();
$part       = 'snippet,contentDetails,player,status'; 

$properties = [
    'snippet.categoryId'            => $this->video->youtube_category_id,
    'snippet.defaultLanguage'       => '',
    'snippet.description'           => $this->video->video_description,
    'snippet.tags[]'                => !empty($this->video->tags->pluck('tag_value')->toArray())?implode(',',$this->video->tags->pluck('tag_value')->toArray()):'',
    'snippet.title'                 => $this->video->video_title,
    'status.embeddable'             => true,
    'status.license'                => '',
    'status.privacyStatus'          => !empty($this->video->privacy_status) ? $this->video->privacy_status : 'private',
    'status.publishAt'      => empty($this->video->video_release_date) ? "" : date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.sP',strtotime($this->video->video_release_date)),
    'status.publicStatsViewable'    => ''
];

if(!empty($this->video->youtube_id)){
  $properties['id'] = $this->video->youtube_id;
}

$service    = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$propertyObject = $this->createResource($properties);
$resource = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Video($propertyObject);

if($this->upload) $client->setDefer(true);

if(!empty($this->video->youtube_id))
{
  $request = $service->videos->update($part, $resource, $params);
}
elseif($this->upload) 
{
  $request = $service->videos->insert($part, $resource, $params);
}
else
{
   exit;
}
```

ive search the internet about this problem but didnt found any solution. Please help thanks.

Note: using this code, upload video is successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my research following are couple of possibilities that can cause the error -

- `status.publishAt` property can only be set if the video's **privacy
  status is private** and the video **has never been published**.
- Setting the `status.publishAt` too close to the current time. Try 60
  minutes. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066193/4273867)

Comment: my problem is im updating the video that has been published. Thats what cause the error. But im confuse because it did not mentioned in the API.

Comment: @KhairulHafizi It's not mentioned in the documentation but I saw it in YouTube API revision history. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history

Comment: I also just found it with the hint from @SauminiNavaratnam in the Revision-History ("This property can only be set if the video's privacy status is private and the video has never been published. ").

I hope someone from YouTube reads this here and update the normal Doscumentation about this issue (means that "publishAt" doesn't work on update, if video was published before..)

Answer (score 2):

The following comes directly from the documentation [PublisedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)

The date and time when the video is scheduled to publish. *It can be set only if the privacy status of the video is private.* The value is specified in **ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ)** format. Note the following two additional points about this property's behavior:

1. If you set this property's value when calling the **videos.update** method, you must also set the **status.privacyStatus** property value to private even if the video is already private.
2. If your request schedules a video to be published at some time in the past, the video will be published right away. As such, the effect of setting the status.publishAt property to a past date and time is the same as of changing the video's privacyStatus from private to public.