# How set time Schedule using YouTube API with C#

Tags: c#, datetime, youtube-api

I've been trying to search and test the code for the past 5 days trying to figure out how to schedule YouTube video publishing using the YouTube API.
I see that YouTube API supports this functionality. `status.PublishAt`
And I also searched on the Internet there are many people saying to use `ISO 8601` format for `status.PublishAt`
I have tried to do this many times. And here is my code:

```
string text_dateschedule = datepicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format_date = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(text_dateschedule, format_date, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);

newVideo.Status.PublishAt = time;
newVideo = await youtubeService.Videos.Update(newVideo, "Id,snippet,status").ExecuteAsync();
```

When I execute it I get the following error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The request metadata specifies an invalid scheduled publishing time. [400]
Errors [
    Message[The request metadata specifies an invalid scheduled publishing time.] Location[body.status.publishAt - other] Reason[invalidPublishAt] Domain[youtube.video]
]
```

Any ideas you guys are welcome to help solve my problem. Best regard!

Comment: Could you try looking into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545477/update-publishat-error-invalidvideometadata-youtube-v3-api-php?

Comment: i viewed it a few day ago. Thankyou

Comment: Please post a [mre] (relevant details are missing).

Comment: I have insert above code to Google Example Code at here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet?hl=en_US#upload_a_video   I don't do any thing. Welcome ideas